# How can I include a saved search folder in a Windows 7 Library?

Tags: windows-7, libraries

For example, add the search for *.avi in the Downloads folder to my Videos library? It's just that I think it's a waste of time to organize my files manually every time I download or copy something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As saved searches are just `.searchconnector-ms` files, you can copy them to folders that are included within your Libraries.